# How to concat Java Flux lists into one list from external sources

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In a spring-boot 2.0 rest controller, I have created the following code which works as desired:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/test3")
Mono<List<String>> test3(){
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("four","five","six");

    return Flux
               .concat(Flux.fromIterable(l1),Flux.fromIterable(l2))
               .collectList();
}
```

My problem comes from trying to do the same thing from an external datasource.  I have created the following test case:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/test4")
Flux<Object> test4(){
    List<String> indecies = Arrays.asList("1","2");
    return Flux.concat(
            Flux.fromIterable(indecies)
        .flatMap(k -> Flux.just(myRepository.getList(k))
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()),2
                )
        ).collectList();
}
```

Where myRepository is the following:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("four","five","six");
    Map<String, List<String>> pm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

MyRepository(){
    pm.put("1", l1);
    pm.put("2", l2);
}

List<String> getList(String key){
    List<String> list = pm.get(key);
    return list;
}   
}
```

My code labeled test4 gives me the code hint error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flux< List < String >> to Publisher < ?
>   extends Publisher < ? extends Object >>

So a few questions:

1. I thought that a Flux was a publisher?  So why the error?
2. What am I doing wrong in test 4 so that it will output the same result as in test3?

The expected output is: [["one","two","three","four","five","six"]]

Comment: `Flux` is a `Publisher` but a `Publisher` isn't a `Flux`. Shouldn't you just use `Flux.fromIterable` instead of `Flux.just`?

Comment: @M.Deinum that worked:

 Mono<List<String>> test6(){
  List<String> indecies = Arrays.asList("1","2");
  
  return Flux.fromIterable(indecies)
          .flatMap(k -> Flux.fromIterable(myRepository.getList(k)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()),2)
          .collectList();
  
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  M. Deinum's comment, here is what works:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/test6")
Mono<List<String>> test6(){
    List<String> indecies = Arrays.asList("1","2");

    return Flux.fromIterable(indecies)
               .flatMap(k -> Flux.fromIterable(myRepository.getList(k)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()),2)
               .collectList();

}
```